# Redgate ANTS Performance Profiler 6.3 gives error: Failed to connect to target process because an exception occurred, "Could not start IIS"

Tags: performance, iis, profiler, redgate, red-gate-ants

Just downloaded a 14 day trial of "ANTS Performance Profiler 6.3" to check performance on my web application.  Here are my configuration settings after beginning a new session (via the File menu).  I'm on Windows 7 and running IIS 7.  This web application is using forms authentication.  I just logged into the site, and to the page I specified in the "ASP.NET web application (URL)" field.  What could cause this error?

I'm taking a wild guess, I need to give the profiler (user) permissions to my web application, yes?  If so, what user can I use?  Or do I need to change the application pool Identity user to something different?

**Download URL:**

http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/

**Settings:**

[image]

**Error (after clicking "Start Profiling" button):**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, when I changed the application pool "Identity" user of my web application from ApplicationPoolIdentity to LocalSystem, it worked.  I suppose I could have also changed the user in the service (Control Panel > Services > ANTS Performance Profiler 6 Service) to some other user and used that user.

[image]

But then I get another error.  As Kip says in Napolean Dynamite, "I love technology."

[image]

**Stack Trace in Details window:**

```
Could not start w3wp as the specified user. Win32 error code: 87
RedGate.Profiler.Engine.Startup.IIS.IISException
stack trace: 
  at ..StartProfilingIIS(String , String )
  at RedGate.Profiler.Engine.Startup.IIS.IISStarter`1.StartProfilingIIS(String currentUserName, String subprocessVariableValue)
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)
rethrown at [0]: 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
  at RedGate.Profiler.Engine.Startup.IIISActuator`1.StartProfilingIIS(String currentUserName, String subprocessVariableValue)
```

**After messing around with the error above for a bit, I tried unchecking this option, and it launched my default browser (which appears to be IE 9).  Seems to be working now.**

[image]